# Multi-Output NN on Keras: Different Models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'd like to design a  FeedForward NN in order to predict 2 outputs using Keras on Tensorflow 2.0.

The function that I want to preditct is basilar:

```
d_1 = u_1+u_2
d_2 = 4*u_2-u_1
```

where `u_1` and `u_2` are the inputs between 0 and 10.

I've tried 2 ways:

**1. A model with 2 braches:**

```
def build_model():
    # Input Layer
    input_layer = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
    
    # First dense hidden layer
    HL_1 = Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(input_layer)

    # Output 1: Output
    O_1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='Output_1')(HL_1)

    # Output 2: Output
    O_2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='Output_2')(HL_1)
    
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[O_1 ,O_2])
    
    return model
```

**2. A model with 2 outpus in the output layer :**

```
def build_model():
    # Input Layer
    input_layer = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
    
    # First dense hidden layer
    HL_1 = Dense(3, activation='relu')(input_layer)

    # Output 1: Output
    Output = Dense(2, activation='relu',name='Output_1')(HL_1)
    
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=Output)
    
    return model
```

The results are completely different. The second model works very well while the first model very badly. My problem is that I don't understand this behavior and I don't understand when I have to use the first or the second model.

Could someone help me? Thank you!

[Model of first attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGp0A.png)

[Model of second attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxzm3.png)

Comment: I think the two are the same so everything else equal they should produce the same results. But you have different activation functions (sigmoid vs relu) in the two models could that explain the difference?

Comment: but the results (loss & rmse) are very different. 
Yes, I've used two different activation functions, but only as a test. The result is the same

Comment: When you use two seperate dense layers, you also have 2 bias weights. If you have two nodes in a single dense layer, you also have only one bias node. probably thats the difference. You could set use_bias=False in the definition of your dense layer and check if they then  perform the same. I could also imagine that there is a difference in the way the gradients are backpropagated.

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work